# Is it possible to convert a Unity Standalone project to Webplayer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am doing my first Unity Standalone game. I don't know if it's possible to convert to Web Player based game from standalone. If there's any documentation about conversion please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press shift+ control+B or go to File-> build settings you will have options to change it towhat ever platform u want(ma be locked according to ur license!). jus select the web Player option, set proper settings for tht platform and click on Build you would get the web player build.

if you are trying to change a Standalone build you have already taken to a web-Player one, It is not possible.. you should take a look into what unity does (or basically what mono does!) to  know the answer why! :)

Answer (score 1):

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Publishing%20Builds.html

You can change your target platform in the Build Settings dialog.